# How can I load an Email attachment to my app?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am developing an Android app.

I already add some setting in Manifest.xml as follow.

```
<intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
     <data android:mimeType="application/pdf" />
     <data android:mimeType="text/html" />
     <data android:mimeType="text/htm" />
</intent-filter>
```

Then, the user can choose my app to open the attachment.

The question is what can I do after that?
How can I access the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll receive an intent in the activity you are declaring this filter. Then, get the URI of the file you're opening:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Uri uri = intent.getData();
```

This URI will probably point to a PDF file. You can read this file like this:

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
InputStream is = cr.openInputStream(uri);
```

If you're interessed in accessing the file directly, I suggest you write your own file from the input stream, since this uri may not necessarily resolve to a real file, and if it does, you may not have permission to read it. Here's a question regarding this case that provides further explanation:

[Retrieve file path from caught DownloadManager intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14364091/retrieve-file-path-from-caught-downloadmanager-intent)

Comment: I can't get he file instance by calling **File f = new File(new URI(uri.toString()));**. I get a runtime exception indicated "java.lang.IllegalArgmentException: Expected file scheme in URI : content://...".

Comment: Please post here the value of `uri.toString()`.

Comment: Open with Email: content://com.android.email.attachmentprovider/1/121/RAW

Comment: Open with gmail: content://gmail-ls/my_gmail_account/message/7869/attachments/0.1/BEST/false

Comment: not able to open the attachment with my app using the above code. value of `uri.tostring()` is `content://com.google.android.email.attachmentprovider/4/941/RAW` and exception I am getting is `FileNotFound`.