# java.lang.SecurityException after splitting activity on two and passing uri through Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-permissions, android-securityexception

I have an app with image editor activity with intent filter

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>

    <data android:mimeType="image/*"/>
</intent-filter>
```

After a while I'd added viewer activity and moved intent filter there.
And added received uri to Intent when openning editor from viewer.
But after doing so I've noticed multiple crushes from users

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.SecurityException
Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadProvider uri content://downloads/all_downloads/250 from pid=4773, uid=10261 requires android.permission.ACCESS_ALL_DOWNLOADS, or grantUriPermission()
```

and

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.SecurityException
Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.telephony.MmsProvider from ProcessRecord{43e44a38 7388:mobi.bcam.editor/u0a230} (pid=7388, uid=10230) requires android.permission.READ_SMS or android.permission.WRITE_SMS
```

So I'm guessing that permission for second activity was not granted. But how I can fix this?

Comment: not sure, check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14364091/retrieve-file-path-from-caught-downloadmanager-intent it looks something related to OS 4.2 and later ...

Comment: You have not provided the java code of your portion.

Comment: Yazan, I've seen this and tried, but still have exception.