# android- DownloadManager SecurityException

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I'm trying ti use `DownloadManager` class in my app to download a file from a url.

```
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
    dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    enqueue = dm.enqueue(request);
```

this code produces:

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadProvider from ProcessRecord{4099d440 5576:com.digitalaria.gama.sample.carousel/10134} (pid=5576, uid=10134) requires android.permission.ACCESS_ALL_DOWNLOADS or android.permission.ACCESS_ALL_DOWNLOADS
```

how to solve the problem?

Comment: Check this link first http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14364091/retrieve-file-path-from-caught-downloadmanager-intent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What version of Android are you trying to run that on ? 
Have a look at this :

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13043

Providing INTERNET and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions should take care of it.

Comment: the Android version is 2.3.3

Comment: Yes thats a bug as reported, can you just try adding the Internet and External Storage permission ? That might solve it